# In an HTML form, how do I copy content of one field to another

Tags: html, forms

I need a button that takes information that you have entered into one `div`, and put it into another. Basically I have one `div` that asks for delivery information, while the other asks for billing info. I want to have a button you can press that checks if you have filled out the delivery info then pressing the button would make the information entered into the delivery information transfer to the billing info. How would I make a button do that?

Comment: first of all, how did a user enter information in a div. I believe what you are asking is for fields in an HTML form. If that is so, please update your question to properly reflect what you are asking. Also, it would be better if you can provide the HTML markup that you have for the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
    document.getElementById('your-button').addEventListener("click", moveContent);
    function moveContent() {
        document.getElementById('your-div').textContent = document.getElementById('other-div').textContent;
    }​
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<button id="your-button">Move Content</button><br />
<div id="other-div">This Text will go into the div below</div>
<div id="your-div">Click button to move text from above text here</div>
```

Comment: what kind of button should i make to use this script?

Comment: It is still saying that no css is assocaited with the button

Answer (score 1):

Make a form, then create an `<input onClick="copy();" type="button" >` tag.  Create a javascript function copy that copies the data.  Do not add a submit attribute to the form.

I.e.,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function copy()
{
    //Copy the data from one div to another.  I recommend setting ID attributes and using document.getElementById(id);
}
</script>
<form>
    <input onClick="copy();" type="button" value="Copy data!" ></input>
</form>
```